# Can I take camping food in hand luggage?

Tags: food-and-drink, camping, hand-luggage, easyjet

Does the current 100ml limit stop me from taking camping food sachets in hand luggage?

I was looking at some today and noticed that the packets were measured in grams not millilitres. Does that mean that they're not liquids? They're really squidgy though so I can see them passing for liquids.

I guess it's up to the security on the day but I wondered if anyone had experience with this.

Comment: From where to where? What type of food? For example, New Zealand will NOT let you bring in fruits from overseas, but will allow most processed foods.

Comment: In many airports (if not all) they will not allow it. If the food is "squidgy" most likely it will be considered liquid. Also, the 100 ml limit thing only applies to liquids in containers that states the volume, if the container does not state the volume, not allowed.

Comment: Curry is considered liquid, Semi Solid foods are considered liquid, so will these food items. Please also check - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25578/carrying-semi-solid-food-in-flights

Comment: Why not take it in checked luggage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prohibition applies to liquids, gels and aerosols. Since you describe the food as squidgy it will with very high probability be considered a gel and not pass.

My advice is to take freeze dried camping foods in your hand luggage. Those are entirely dry and pass without any problems (source: I do this all the time).